# visual studio 2019 ui problem The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000A)

Tags: user-interface

i have problem in visual studio 2019 from long time ago
it need a couple of restart to work ? is there any solution guys , many thanks

[enter image description here][1]

```
 
        1 Error   
      
        Why am I seeing this page?   
     
     
      
     
      
       The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000A)     
     
      
     
      
     
    Instances of this error (1)  
     
    1.   Hide Call Stack 
     
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Designer.Interfaces.IVSMDCodeDomProvider.get_CodeDomProvider()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_Provider()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_CompileUnit()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)  
     

 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5blAr.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and issue disappeared after upgrading Visual Studio to version: 16.11.18